# Buildroot: how to build device tree overlay (dtbo) from out of tree dts source files?

Tags: linux-kernel, overlay, buildroot, device-tree

I would like to use buildroot 2022.11 to generate and apply devive tree overlay automatically during build.

When using the options BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTS_SUPPORT and BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_DTS_PATH, my custom device tree source “dts” file is built into a “dtb” file by buildroot. But, actually, I would like to compile it as a “dtbo” file so that it can be added as overlay to an existing board main “dts” file.
Is there any possibility to have buildroot generating “dtbo” files from a list of out of tree “dts” files?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used buildroot so cannot answer your question. But as an aside, note that the base system dtb needs to be built with the `-@` dtc option so that it will contain the `__symbols__` node required for resolving references in overlays. That can be done by enabling the `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTB_OVERLAY_SUPPORT` option in buildroot.